# How to Invoke Selenium class from clicking Html Button using tomcat

Tags: java, html, selenium, tomcat, servlets

I have three test case in different java file and want to invoke it using tomcat server by clicking html button. This is my html

```
<form action="case1" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="sele" name="button"  value="TestCase1">
    <input type="submit" id="sele1" value="TestCase2">
    <input type="submit" id="sele2" value="TestCase3">
</form>
```

After clicking button it will check which button is clicked in servlet and invoke respective class , one button example

```
String button = req.getParameter("button");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
if ("TestCase1".equals(button)) {
try {
   out.println("Started");
   Sele s=new Sele();
   s.sele();
   out.println("Ended");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output screen show **Started and Ended** but it didnt invoke Selenium class. And Not Showing any error or Exception, My selenium class code

```
public class Sele{  
    public void sele() throws InterruptedException, IOException{  
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/java/jar/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/first/index2.html");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

But if i Execute this java code in through command prompt it invoke Selenium class

```
public Remote{
 void remote(){
   Sele s=new Sele();
   s.sele();
 }
}
```

Code work correctly and open chrome as automated for above code but not in server can any one help me out here.....

Answer (score 0):

In sele class I added debugger Address and open in particular port to see what went wrong and you can able trigger new browser from already opened browser to ren selenium script